# problems with if condition in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, if-statement, conditional-statements

I tried to render a file if it is true.

my code is

```
<% if @orbituarysite.notice_display.nil? %>
  <%= render 'notice_displays/form' , :remote => true %>
<% end %>
```

I tried it in console it shows true, this is the output

```
1.9.3-p194 :024 > b=Orbituarysite.find(1)
1.9.3-p194 :025 > b.notice_display
NoticeDisplay Load (1.4ms)  SELECT "notice_displays".* FROM "notice_displays" WHERE "notice_displays"."orbituarysite_id" = 1 LIMIT 1
=> nil 
1.9.3-p194 :026 > b.notice_display.nil?
=> true
```

here it shows true and i'm unable to render my form, though i have my value true
Please tell me what am i missing?

Comment: Can you please share the form code? Because normally we forgot to give <%= in form_for or form tag. I guess you have used <% form_for %>

Answer (score 0):

You have to make it like this :-

```
<% if @orbituarysite.notice_display.nil? %>
  <%= render 'notice_displays/form' %>
<% end %>
```

in notice_displays/_form

```
<%=form_for....., :remote => true%>
```